# Set session variable with select box via jQuery/ Ajax with Coldfusion

Tags: ajax, forms, coldfusion, jquery

Ok so here is my epic journey problem going on for a month now...:

First problem: I was building a form with coldfusion-ajax tags which was the worst mistake ever. IE completely hates it and I was unable to bind anything. YES, my code was correct. I had it verified by many people and many forums. So I have NO IDEA what was wrong.

So coldfusion ajax tags are out of the question..they won't work with my server setup...I don't know. (I don't control my server I work on)

So...now that i'm SOL and crying in my office like a crazy person... I have now decided to go around the problem by using jQuery + Coldfusion.

It isn't working either...

**Here is the new problem:**
I need to have a select box that was pre-populated **set a session variable**. In other words:

I want to pass a form variable to a page that will set the session variable equal to that form variable...

Note: I'm using CF 8.

Here is my code so far:

form:

```
<form>
    <select name="DeptCode" id = "dept">
    <option value="NONE" selected>Choose a Department
    <cfoutput query="getDepartments">
    <option value="#DeptCode#">#DeptName#</option>
    </cfoutput>
    </select>
    </form>
    <cfoutput> #session.DeptCode#</cfoutput>
```

jQuery/Ajax:

```
<script language = "javascript">
$('#dept').change(
        function() {

            var datas = $('#dept').val();
            $.ajax({
            url: 'url:catch.cfc?method=getDept',
            data: {dept: datas}
            success: function(datas) { alert(datas); }
             });
}); 
</script>
```

catch.cfc

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
    <cffunction name="setDept" access="remote" returntype="any">
        <cfargument name="dept" type="any" required="yes">
        <cfset session.DeptCode = #argument.dept#>
        <cfreturn />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: In theory, CFID and CFSESSIONID in cookie will be sent along, then your catch.cfc should be able to set session.DeptCode.  So what's not working? try some logging in catch.setDept() and see if u can debug it.

Comment: Its not doing anything. :( It is the ajax stuff that isn't working. It won't pass the variables. So I will choose a selection in the select box, but it will not change the variable.

Firebug isn't picking anything up.

Comment: I think something is wrong in my jquery script..i'm not sure trying to figure it out now..firebug isn't helping one bit. It does nothing.

Comment: UPDATE: I figured out where the problem is kind of..

.val isn't working ... i get undefined everytime.. any ideas..? I'm desperate.

Comment: UPDATE: I got the jquery to work. But now I am getting "Element dept is undefined in argument." Any idea?

Comment: do <cfdump var="#arguments#" and see what you get, also check in firebux whats sent.

Comment: Note, rolled back to revision 1. With "questions" it is better to preserve the *actual* code, because changes (however correct) may obscure the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you've updated things since posting your code, or maybe there were typos during transcription -- but there are some syntax problems:

```
$('#dept').change( function() {
  var datas = $('#dept').val(); // always yields a result in real code?
  $.ajax({
    url: 'catch.cfc?method=getDept', // You repeated "url:" in your url
    data: {dept: datas}, // added missing final comma
    success: function(datas) { alert(datas); }
  });
});
```

Just a thought.

Comment: thanks I figured this out finally before you posted! But thanks soo much! (I had forgot to say it was answered.. xD)